# How to speed up ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync() in React Native using the Expo managed workflow?

Tags: react-native, expo

Here is my code.

```
    let result: any = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
        mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
        allowsMultipleSelection: true,
        selectionLimit: 8,
        videoExportPreset: ImagePicker.VideoExportPreset.H264_640x480,
    });
```

When posting on Twitter, when you select your videos or photos they immediately are shown after the camera roll is closed. On my app it can take close to a minute for a 1 minute video. Does anyone know why this process takes so long? I also want to limit videos to a max of 30 seconds. I can't get the video duration until after it is loaded which takes quite a long time so the user has to wait 30 seconds or more just to find out that they can't upload it. If I was able to speed up the process I wouldn't have to worry about this. If it can't be sped up then is there a way to limit the camera roll options to photos and videos less than 30 seconds? Thanks.